# Python Folium export map error via pdfkit and selenium

Tags: python, extract, folium, file-conversion, html-to-pdf

I have to extract Folium map to pgn/img.
I've tried a lot of path, via selenium, converting to pdf and reconvert to png, pdfkit, imgkit but nothing worked...
Some help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with Selenium :

1. You create your map with folium as an HTML file
2. You open your Selenium browser at the url `file://{your_folder_path}/{your_HTML_map_file}`
3. You wait for a few seconds in order to use the method `save_screenshot()` from your Selenium browser